# Does Spring Framework security 3.2.10 completely supports Thymeleaf 3.0.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a fully developed spring project, I am using spring security version 3.2.10 it is working fine with thymeleaf 2, I want to know whether thymeleaf 3.0.6 supports or fully compatible with spring security 3.2.10 version.

I googled so much but I didn't got answer for my doubt.Please someone help me whether thymeleaf 3.0.6 completely compatible with spring security 3.2.10 and I don't want to change or upgrade  the spring security 3.2.10 version.

Comment: Do you mean the thymeleaf-extras? Thymeleaf core and Spring Security does not have much integration.

Comment: yaa thymeleaf core and spring security core, not thymeleaf-extras.